# reload subclass of frozenset

Tags: python, inheritance, python-3.x, set

I have a class which I want to have all the functions of frozenset but i don't want him to be configurable (by init, frozenset gets iterable).

Additionally, I want him to have the function 'reload' - I am loading static list from a server so the user can not change it (so I don't want the user to think he can change it).
The list on the server can be changed by the admin so I need the reload option.

That's what I hoped for:

```
class A(frozenset):
    def __init__(self, list_id):
        super().__init__()
        self.list_id = list_id
        self.reload()

    def reload(self):
        #loading staff by self.list_id...
        pass
```

But I didn't find a way to 'add' new staff to the class (I tried to re-init it).

May be I am using the wrong staff so if you have anther way for this it fine (I need the option to compare difference between to difference objects):

```
a = A(1)
b = A(2)
len(a)
iter(a)
a.difference(b)
```

May be overloading add and update of set will be good but i don't want to do that (it looks bad in code because there are more update-like functions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot update the `frozenset` contents, no; it remains immutable even when subclassed.

You can subclass the [`collections.abc.Set()` Abstract Base Class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Set) instead; it models an immutable set too; all you need to do really is implement the methods listed in the [*Abstract Methods* column](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections-abstract-base-classes) and the rest is taken care of for you:

```
from collections.abc import Set

class A(Set):
    def __init__(self, list_id):
        self.list_id = list_id
        self.reload()

    def reload(self):
        values = get_values(self.list_id)
        self._values = frozenset(values)

    def __contains__(self, item):
        return item in self._values

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._values)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._values)
```

Not *all* methods of the [built-in `frozenset` type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) are implemented; you can easily supply the missing ones as these are aliases of the operator methods:

```
def issubset(self, other):
    return self <= frozenset(other)

def issuperset(self, other):
    return self >= frozenset(other)

def union(self, *others):
    res = self
    for o in others:
        res |= frozenset(o)
    return res

def intersection(self, *others):
    res = self
    for o in others:
        res &= frozenset(o)
    return res

def difference(self, *others):
    res = self
    for o in others:
        res -= frozenset(o)
    return res

def symmetric_difference(self, other):
    return self ^ frozenset(other)
```